# to retrieve the list of stock data by product ID using catalogInventoryStockItemList in android using k2 soap

Tags: android

Hi I want to display is the stock of particular product available in my android app where I want to retrive the products through k2 soap api through catalogInventoryStockItemList method.

Please can anyone guide me how to proceed to this?

```
public  void getproductstock(){

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "catalogInventoryStockItemList");
//SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try
{
    androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
    String result = response.getProperty(4).toString();
    tv_products.setText(result);
}
catch(Exception e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

But i am unable to fetch and display is_in_stock attribute of particular product in textview